# What is the relationship between the number of nodes and the height of a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am new to coding, and all its glory. However, I have a project where I am supposed to find the relationship betweeen the number of nodes in a Binary Search Tree, and the height of the Binary Search Tree.

I've seen where people said that N = 2^h (where N = number of nodes, and h = height of the Binary Search Tree), however with my Binary Search Tree, but that is not the case.

P.S.: Here is my code to find the height of the BST

```
int findHeight(NodePtr node) {

if (node == NULL)
    return -1;

else
    {

    int lHeight = findHeight(node->left);
    int rHeight = findHeight(node->right);

    if (lHeight > rHeight)
        return(lHeight + 1);

    else
        return(rHeight + 1);
    }
}
```

Any answers would be great. Thanks

Comment: Is it a balanced tree?

Comment: If the tree is balanced, then the N=2^h algorithm works. If the tree is not balanced... balance it :)

Comment: Thank both of you so much! How would I check to see if it is balanced?

Comment: its balanced if its a balanced tree. i.e. each time an element is inserted the tree shuffles its nodes around to ensure it is split into branches of a similar length. If you're coding your own tree its a virtual certainty its not balanced. One example of a balanced binary tree is a [red black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), its a complex data structure. To see tree balancing in all its gory glory see [here](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_bst2.aspx).